# Spring Boot and JPA+Postges: Lob mapped to Text but integer is persisted

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I created a simple Spring Boot application with JPA connecting to a Postgres database. I want to store large text files in the database and for that I am using the `@Lob` annotation on a String attribute, which JPA successfully maps to a Text type in Postgres. However, when I persist an entity to the database, the text contents are always saved as an unrelated integer. A varchar is persisted as expected. Please see the snippets below. What am I missing here?

(some lines omitted for simplification purposes)

SampleEntity.java:

```
@Entity
public class SampleEntity {
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String varcharTest;

  @Lob
  private String textTest;
...
}
```

SampleRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleEntity, Long> {
}
```

My application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://myserver:32432/postgres
    username: postgres
    password: <password>
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        SampleEntity se = new SampleEntity();
        se.setTextTest("abc1234");
        se.setVarcharTest("xyz5678");
        SampleRepository sampleRepo = ctx.getBean(SampleRepository.class);
        sampleRepo.save(se);
```

[image: Database Select]

Comment: The only JPA here is the Entity, no persistence.xml, no entityManager... everything else is Spring. Perhaps you should change the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CLOB` datatype is currently [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html) in postgres database. You can use `text` datatype instead. To save data in string format just use `@Column(columnDefinition = "text")` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an OID to the actual file that is stored outside the table. It's the default behavior for a @Lob field.

Comment: But when I run a `SELECT` statement against the field I also get this OID. How am I supposed to retrieve the contents remotely?

Comment: I guess you could use lo_get(textTest) function in your statement to get the content as described here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174029/how-to-show-large-objects-lob-contents